# Rtx 3060 or ps5: what should I opt for gaming?

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming

I want to build a gaming pc but my friend told me that it will cost me more than playstation. Will ps5 good for me when compared to rtx 3060.

Comment: The most important question your need to answer for yourself is "What games do you want to play?", that might entirely rule out one option or the other. There are lots of games exclusive to Playstation and even more games for PC that don't work well with controllers so will never come to any console.

Comment: And also, with a strong PC you can emulate consoles too, that ain't happening with the PS5 (except maybe old playstations, but that ain't gonna run SM64 or Mario Kart...)

Answer (score 1):

3060 is way better than the ps5 even with 16gb of vram because ull have at least 16 gbs of ram on that PC to start up application and some of the ram helps the GPU out in games so if u have 12 gb and 16gb of ddr4 u get half of that and end up with 20 gb of vram all together so the PC CPU will have to be same speed as the ps5 for it to compete cause the 3060 can easily outperform the ps5 at its 300$ price point.

Answer (score 0):

Ps5 have a bus 256bit vs 192 bit of 3060 rtx 12 GB GDDR6 of RAM. Vs 16 GB GDDR6
The RX 6700 can beat this GPU (ps5 It's likes the RX 6700GPU but more faster) the ps5 GPU like a RX 6700xt more powerful than a rtx 3060